# Hamiltonian Graph Way

Tags: graphs, hamiltonian-circuit

Recently i studied three theorems which says about Hamiltonian graph,
they are as follows,

1. Dirac's Theorem: Let G be some simple graph of order n >= 3,

for all vertices of the graph G, its degree >= n/2 then we say given simple graph is actually an Hamiltonian graph.

2. Ore's Theorem: Let G be a simple graph of order n >=3,

sum of degree of any two vertices which are not adjacent >= n then we say given simple graph is an Hamiltonian graph.

3. Another is a simple graph with (n-1) C 2 edges + 2 edges implies its an Hamiltonian graph.

given this basic definition, my question is will this even work in reverse manner, suppose if i give an hamiltonian graph will all this theorem satisfy?
Below is one question i am wondering about!!

[image]

thankyou in advance! :)

Comment: Will what work in reverse manner?  What does it mean to "work in reverse manner"?  We're not looking for posts that just have the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it for you.  What are your thoughts?  What progress have you made?  Have you tried working through some examples?  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  You've been given this feedback before.  We require you to provide proper attribution to your sources: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Hi @D.W. , i will take care, will use Latex next time! thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a graph $G$ that is a single cycle of length $\geqslant 5$. Then it should be clear that none of the properties is true, while $G$ is hamiltonian.

Comment: yeah it is trivial! thanks @Nathaniel